# Running script to check network connectivity at sturtup

Tags: networking, scripts, startup

I've got a VM on hyper-v Runnung Ubuntu 20.04 LTS connected to two nics one external (eth0) and one internal (eth1) as I will be connecting through several networks (home and university mainly) and I want the VM to run a script at sturtup to check if I have network connectivity on eth0 disabling eth1 if not diasble eth0

These is the script i wrote

```
#!/bin/bash

ifconfig eth0 up
ifconfig eth1 up
r=0
for i in {1..10}
do
    ping -c 1 192.168.1.1 > /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ];
    then
        r=1
        break
    fi
done
if [ $r -eq 1 ];
then
    echo "eth0 is up"
    echo "disabling internal network"
    ifconfig eth1 down
else
    echo "eth0 is down"
    echo "disabling external network"
    ifconfig eth0 down
fi
```

It works but doesn't seem to do what i want.
Infact if i run ping to 192.168.1.1 it gets responses but the script disables eth0.
The script is set to run at startup with this systemd unit

```
[Unit]
After=network.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/network-check.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

EDIT1 updated script

Comment: Welcome, I think you mean `result=1`, `result=0`?

Comment: In which sense? `if result = 1` isn't that the same as `if $result = 1` or before where i set the variable?
The logic is test 10 times if you get a ping; if you get at least one positive then exit and disable eth1 else disable eth0

Edit

Comment: I'm talking about [this](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/varassignment.html). And `[$result -eq 1]` should be `[ $result -eq 1 ] ` . Are all of those typos?

Comment: If I remove the dollar sign it gives me a "command not found" error
I tried also moving the result declaration before the loop but it continues giving me that it fails to ping eth0 (disabling it)

Comment: It's not just about removing the dollar sign. There must be no spaces in the assignation: `result=1`, not  `result = 1`. You are performing an assignation, that's the correct syntax.

Comment: See my comment above, you still have spaces in the assignations.

Comment: Oh ok, my error, it works now, didn't know that in bash script assignations had to be without spaces. works perfectly now! Thanks

Comment: I'm new to bash script, and in programming i always use spaces before and after = signs

Comment: Ha, it's true. Always check the syntax, the link I provided is useful.

Comment: Always feed your scripts through `shellcheck`, install the `shellcheck` package or paste your script into `https://www.shellcheck.net`. Always.